# Exclude single list item from numbering

Tags: html, css, list

I have the following list:

```
<ol>
   <li class="caption">Caption</li>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

I would like to have the first li without any number and the second item starting with number 1. Is this possible by just using CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, simply `display` to `block`, so that the item will not be displayed as a list item at all and will thus also be excluded from the numbering.

```css
.caption { display: block; }
```

```html
<ol>
   <li class="caption">Caption</li>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```css
ol{list-style:none;}
ol {
        counter-reset:yourCounter;
 }
ol li:not(.caption) {
  counter-increment:yourCounter;
  list-style:none;
}
ol li:not(.caption):before {
  content:counter(yourCounter) ".";
}
ol li.caption:before {
  content:""; 
}
```

```html
Try following code

<ol>
   <li class="caption">Caption</li>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS counters like so

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: index;
}

li + li {  
   counter-increment: index; 
}

li + li:before {
   content : counter(index);
   padding-right: .5em;
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogNLBw

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a simple solution by accident. Using the following CSS

```
.caption {
  display: block; /* default for list items would be "display: list-item;" */
}
```

seems to exclude the item from numbering. Tested in FF 33, Chrome 38 and IE 11.

Thanks for the other answers but this seems to be the simplest solution. Any problems with that? If not i'll accept it as the answer.